# Collapsing Sidebar with Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, sidebar

I just visited this page [http://www.elmastudio.de/](https://web.archive.org/web/20131015001517/https://www.elmastudio.de/) and wondered if it is possible to build the left sidebar collapse with Bootstrap 3.

Code to collapse the sidebar from the top (phone only):

```html
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".sidebar-ex1-collapse">
    <span class="sr-only">Sidebar</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span>
</button>
```

Sidebar itself has the hidden-xs class. It is removed with the following js

```js
$('.sidebar-toggle').click(function(){
     $('#sidebar').removeClass('hidden-xs');            
});
```

If you click the button it toggles the sidebar from the top. It be great to see the sidebar behave like the website above shows. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do we all agree that http://www.elmastudio.de/ no longer has that sidebar collapse?

Comment: Also checkout these useful bootstrap sidebar menu collections
http://www.designerslib.com/bootstrap-sidebar-menu-templates/

Answer (score 128, accepted):

**Bootstrap 3**

Yes, it's possible. This "off-canvas" example should help to get you started.

https://codeply.com/p/esYgHWB2zJ

Basically you need to wrap the layout in an outer div, and use media queries to toggle the layout on smaller screens.

```
/* collapsed sidebar styles */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .row-offcanvas {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    right: -41.6%;
  }

  .row-offcanvas-left
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    left: -41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-right.active {
    right: 41.6%;
  }
  .row-offcanvas-left.active {
    left: 41.6%;
  }
  .sidebar-offcanvas {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 41.6%;
  }
  #sidebar {
    padding-top:0;
  }
}
```

Also, there are several [more Bootstrap sidebar examples here](https://medium.com/wdstack/bootstrap-sidebar-examples-e363021395ff)

---

**Bootstrap 4**

[Create a responsive navbar sidebar "drawer" in Bootstrap 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996084/)

Comment: @Delucia: it works on Chrome on Android. Bootply itself doesn't work correctly, but click the "Switch to render view" link.

Comment: [here](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/dashboard/) is official bootstrap **dashboard template with sidebar**

Comment: @stom: It hides on the mobile and tablet versions which is the issue.

Answer (score 25):

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/

This is the official example, may be better for some.  It is under their Experiments examples section, but since it is official, it should be kept up to date with the current bootstrap release.

Looks like they have added an off canvas css file used in their example:

http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/offcanvas.css

And some JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
    $('.row-offcanvas').toggleClass('active')
  });
});
```

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: I've added one more option for bootstrap sidebars.

There are actually three manners in which you can make a bootstrap 3 sidebar. I tried to keep the code as simple as possible.

## Fixed sidebar

Here you can see a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/pckUqtKEMD) of a simple fixed sidebar I've developed with the same height as the page

## Sidebar in a column

I've also developed a rather simple column sidebar that works in a two or three column page inside a container. It takes the length of the longest column. Here you can see a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/ODtOcZ2WOT)

## Dashboard

If you google bootstrap dashboard, you can find multiple suitable dashboard, such as [this one](http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/admin-dashboard/). However, most of them require a lot of coding. I've developed a dashboard that works without additional javascript (next to the bootstrap javascript). Here is a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/r9Prza34wB)

For all three examples you off course have to include the jquery, bootstrap css, js and theme.css files.

## Slidebar

If you want the sidebar to hide on pressing a button this is also possible with only a little javascript.Here is a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/EOgJSIzPGS)

Answer (score 6):

Via Angular: using `ng-class` of Angular, we can hide and show the side bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/359/

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%" ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="showgraphSidebar ? 'col-xs-3' : 'hidden'" id="colPush" >
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div ng-class="showgraphSidebar ? 'col-xs-9' : 'col-xs-12'"  id="colMain"  >
        <button  ng-click='toggle()' >Sidebar Toggle</a>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.showgraphSidebar = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.showgraphSidebar = !$scope.showgraphSidebar;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not mentioned on doc, but Left sidebar on Bootstrap 3 is possible using "Collapse" method.

As mentioned by bootstrap.js :

```
Collapse.prototype.dimension = function () {
    var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
    return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
  }
```

This mean, adding class "width" into target, will expand by width instead of height :

http://jsfiddle.net/2316sfbz/2/

Comment: How would you do it to hide the left menu only 80% and show a small button to expand again the menu?