# Bootstrap 3 collapsible sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Who could please tell me what would be the simplest and cleanest way to do exactly the same sidebar navigation as this website : http://www.makerstudios.com/ (but on the left side)

Using bootstrap 3

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like an exact duplicate of [Collapsing Sidebar with Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397140/collapsing-sidebar-with-bootstrap-3)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a super useful plugin / add-on for Bootstrap 3. It is called **[Jasny Bootstrap](http://jasny.github.io/bootstrap/)** and among the many features, one is an off-canvas navigation. The looks and feels of it is very much like Bootstrap, so if that is your framework of choice (like for me), I highly recommend this.

I had some issue with the sidebar closing automatically after each click in the menu, so the fix for that (if you need it) was to add `data-autohide="false"` to the button that opens the panel. This way it stays open until the user clicks on a 'CLOSE' link.

```
<a data-toggle="offcanvas" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas="body" data-autohide="false">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: do I need jquery for this?

Comment: @Shardul Yes, you need jquery

Answer (score 12):

I found this fiddle it may help you as well <kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/YJB4q/11/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<body>
    <nav class='sidebar sidebar-menu-collapsed'> <a href='#' id='justify-icon'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify'></span>
      </a>

        <ul class='level1'>
            <li class='active'> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Dashboard'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Dashboard</span>
          </a>

                <ul class='level2'>
                    <li> <a href='#' title='Traffic'>Traffic</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#' title='Conversion rate'>Conversion rate</a>

                    </li>
                    <li> <a href='#' title='Purchases'>Purchases</a>

                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='APIs'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-wrench collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>APIs</span>
          </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Settings'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cog collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Settings</span>
          </a>

            </li>
            <li> <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Account'>
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-user collapsed-element'></span>
            <span class='expanded-element'>Account</span>
          </a>

            </li>
        </ul> <a href='#' id='logout-icon' title='Logout'>
        <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></span>
      </a>

    </nav>
</body>
```

css

```
@import url('http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
 @import url("//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css");
 body {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}
nav.sidebar-menu-collapsed {
    width: 44px;
}
nav.sidebar-menu-expanded {
    width: auto;
}
nav.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099ff;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px 10px;
}
nav.sidebar a#justify-icon {
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
}
nav.sidebar a#logout-icon {
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: normal;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable {
    outline: 0;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 0px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable:hover {
    color: #bbbbbb;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li a.expandable span.expanded-element {
    display: none;
    font-size: 11px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 5px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active {
    margin-left: -4px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active a.expandable {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white !important;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 4px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 li.active a.expandable:hover {
    color: white !important;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 {
    margin: 20px 6px 20px 30px;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-bottom: solid white 1px;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
nav.sidebar ul.level1 ul.level2 li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: 0;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

jQuery

```
(function () {
    $(function () {
        var SideBAR;
        SideBAR = (function () {
            function SideBAR() {}

            SideBAR.prototype.expandMyMenu = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-menu-expanded");
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.collapseMyMenu = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-expanded").addClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed");
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.showMenuTexts = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").show();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.hideMenuTexts = function () {
                return $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").hide();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.showActiveSubMenu = function () {
                $("li.active ul.level2").show();
                return $("li.active a.expandable").css({
                    width: "100%"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.hideActiveSubMenu = function () {
                return $("li.active ul.level2").hide();
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.adjustPaddingOnExpand = function () {
                $("ul.level1 li a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "1px 4px 4px 0px"
                });
                return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "1px 4px 4px 4px"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse = function () {
                $("ul.nbs-level1 li a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "4px 4px 4px 0px"
                });
                return $("ul.level1 li.active a.expandable").css({
                    padding: "4px"
                });
            };

            SideBAR.prototype.ignite = function () {
                return (function (instance) {
                    return $("#justify-icon").click(function (e) {
                        if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed")) {
                            instance.adjustPaddingOnExpand();
                            instance.expandMyMenu();
                            instance.showMenuTexts();
                            instance.showActiveSubMenu();
                            $(this).css({
                                color: "#000"
                            });
                        } else if ($(this).parent("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-expanded")) {
                            instance.resetOriginalPaddingOnCollapse();
                            instance.collapseMyMenu();
                            instance.hideMenuTexts();
                            instance.hideActiveSubMenu();
                            $(this).css({
                                color: "#FFF"
                            });
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                })(this);
            };

            return SideBAR;

        })();
        return (new SideBAR).ignite();
    });

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer but i will use no0ne's plugin.

Comment: @4dgaurav : the jsfiddle doesn't expand - any ideas? - Oh never mind - I got it going...

Comment: @Josey I just didn't copy the info properly. He has a link to a working version at the top anyway

Answer (score 7):

EDIT: I've added one more option for bootstrap sidebars.

There are actually three manners in which you can make a bootstrap 3 sidebar. I tried to keep the code as simple as possible.

## Fixed sidebar

Here you can see a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/pckUqtKEMD) of a simple fixed sidebar I've developed with the same height as the page

## Sidebar in a column

I've also developed a rather simple column sidebar that works in a two or three column page inside a container. It takes the length of the longest column. Here you can see a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/ODtOcZ2WOT)

## Dashboard

If you google bootstrap dashboard, you can find multiple suitable dashboard, such as [this one](http://startbootstrap.com/template-categories/admin-dashboard/). However, most of them require a lot of coding. I've developed a dashboard that works without additional javascript (next to the bootstrap javascript). Here is a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/r9Prza34wB)

For all three examples you off course have to include the jquery, bootstrap css, js and theme.css files.

For making the sidebar transposable you need a simple javascript file that transposes the desired sidebar, such as given in other answers on this page or [here](http://plugins.adchsm.me/slidebars)

## Slidebar

If you want the sidebar to hide on pressing a button this is also possible with only a little javascript.Here is a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/EOgJSIzPGS)

Answer (score 5):

This solution is only for people who use Angular. Using `ng-class` of Angular, we can hide and show the side bar.

http://jsfiddle.net/DVE4f/359/

```
<div class="container" style="width:100%" ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<div class="row">
    <div ng-class="showgraphSidebar ? 'col-xs-3' : 'hidden'" id="colPush" >
        Sidebar
    </div>
    <div ng-class="showgraphSidebar ? 'col-xs-9' : 'col-xs-12'"  id="colMain"  >
        <button  ng-click='toggle()' >Sidebar Toggle</a>
    </div>    
  </div>
</div>
```

.

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.showgraphSidebar = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.showgraphSidebar = !$scope.showgraphSidebar;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any idea how to add slide animation?

Comment: Have you took a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249373/slide-left-animated-transition-in-ng-hide-ng-animate?