# Slide Left animated transition in ng-hide, ng-Animate

Tags: angularjs, css, ng-animate

I have created jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/99vtukjk/
On clicking left or right text, currently the animation for hide is upwards, how can we change it to slide left animation e.g slide & fade to left menubar?.

```
   <body ng-app="myApp1">
       <div id='outerdiv' ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
             <div ng-click="myValue=true" >LEFT</div>
             <div  ng-click="myValue=false">RIGHT</div>
               <div id="one" class='animate-hide'  ng-hide="myValue"> 
               this is just a sample div
               </div>
         {{myValue}}
       </div>
   </body>
```

CSS:

```
.animate-hide {
 -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  line-height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide {
  line-height:0;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

Angular Module

```
  var app = angular.module("myApp1", ["ngAnimate"]);
    app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
    $scope.myValue=false;
    });
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you can set `left: 0` on `.animate-hide`

and `left: -100%` on `.animate-hide.ng-hide`

here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvpdnjps/)

One thing that can help you make beautiful animations is using 
[Animate.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

> animate.css is a bunch of cool, fun, and cross-browser animations for you to use in your projects.

Answer (score 13):

Check out [ngAnimate](https://github.com/Augus/ngAnimate/). Amazing.

[DEMO](http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/)

Comment: It is awesome! I was about a couple of hours trying to accomplish this. Solved the problem. Thank you!