# Angular slide a div on swipe similar to archive in gmail or outlook

Tags: angularjs, swipe

So am trying to slide a div on swipe using angular.(The swipe functionality on a row in iOS)
I have tried a couple of libraries but it doesn't to achieve what I need.

1. ngswipeitem
2. awesome-angular-swipe
3. swipe-li

I need to show div containing archive on swipe similar to the archive in outlook

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item.Subject}}</div> 
    <div>Archive</div> <!--this div is hidden and I need to show it on swipe-->
</div>
```

Comment: have you tried https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch/directive/ngSwipeLeft

Comment: @user93 this one will show the div,my problem is in the animation or sliding the required div.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26249373/slide-left-animated-transition-in-ng-hide-ng-animate

Comment: @user93 I already checked that.I need to do it using swipe.My problem is with the transition and the swipe

Comment: could you please post the plunker of the code

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Hammerjs and Angular Hammer.
My problem was in the ng-repeater.I had to loop all the divs.

Html:

```
<div class="Swiper" ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div>{{item.Subject}}</div> 
    <div class="Page">Archive</div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.Page,
.Swiper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
}

.Swiper {

    overflow: hidden;
}

    .Swiper.animate > .Page {
        transition: all .3s;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    }

.Page {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

    padding: 0 10px;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;

    padding-top: 10%;

}
```

The problem:

```
 var div = document.querySelector('.Swiper');
 var outer = new HammerCarousel(div, Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL, docId);
```

The Solution:

```
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('.Swiper');
            for (i = 0; i < divs.length; ++i) {
                var outer = new HammerCarousel(divs[i], Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL, docId);
            }
```